# How to bind the data from a string in asp:grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, gridview

I have a following string :

```
for(#some conditions){    
 ##
result += "<tr><td>" + dc + "</td><td>" + al + "</td><tr>"; 
}
```

Now, i want to show the load the vlaue of `dc` and `al` in my HTML input text area using the `aspx:grid`.

For example the value of result is:

```
result =  <tr><td>1111</td><td>23</td><td><tr><td>22222</td><td>43</td><tr>
```

Now i want to show the data in the following format using `grid`

```
dc       al
1111     23
222222   43
```

For now, I am filling the text area using the following commands.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function submit_a()
    {
        $.post("../AllocationValidator.aspx", { "data": escape(validatorXML), "scenarioID": scenarioID }, function (result) {
            alert("Data Saved!");
            $("#allocations").empty();
            $("#allocations").html(result);
            BodyLoad();
        });
    }    
</script>

<div id = "allocations" style = "width: 650px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid black;height: 150px; overflow:scroll;"></div>
```

My question is how to implement the `asp:grid` to display the data ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Where is the grid?

Comment: There is no grid , but i want to put it at the given id i.e. "allocationstatus"

Comment: Why do you need a grid? isn't plain html table enough?

Comment: @AmiramKorach Actually my boss need it . I had already done with the simple HTML :(
Is it possible to do it ?

Comment: Is there a reason why a grid should be better? In client side the grid is turning into an html table.

Comment: @AmiramKorach Tuely speaking , Even i don't know :P
It is all for the future purpose

Comment: OK. You need to make a table in html and set the thead th tags and leave tbody empty. Set an ID for tbody, find it with jquery and set its html. If you want to do it with a grid, add a grid with column definitions and false data.  Client side is the same.

Comment: @AmiramKorach but how to pass the data source. I have never use grid without using datasource. Would you please write the syntax for me ?

Comment: Use an ObjectDataSource. In the SelectMethod create a dummy object with properties like your columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to display your retrieved data in a GridView control. You can either bind a data source to the control or add columns and rows programmatically.

You can bind any data sources that implement the IListSource or IList interface. This means that you cannot bind your `result` string directly, as noted in your question title. You have to store your retrieved data in a compatible data structure like for example a List to bind it as the data source.

To use databinding, you could save your `dc` and `al` in a dictionary-like data structure. Assuming that you only want to display two columns of data.

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (/* Condition */)
{ 
    data.Add(dc, al);
}
grid.DataSource = data;
grid.DataBind();
```

The corresponding grid would be

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Key" HeaderText="dc"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Value" HeaderText="al" />
</Columns> 
</asp:GridView>
```

If you are using a foreach to generate your `result` string, than you should look at the possibility to use the object in the foreach statement as your data source.